# How does a child develop "handed-ness"?

Tags: toddler, behavior, development, fine-motor-skills

I've noticed that my son generally experiments fine motor skills initially using his left-hand (stacking, eating with utensils, coloring) and then shifts to using his right more often.  I'm honestly not sure if there's a hand he prefers or if he just goes with the one that's closer to the object to be manipulated.  When does a child typically settle on a dominant hand?  Additionally his grandfather (mother's father) is ambidextrous, is that a genetic trait that's often passed along?

Answer (score 6):

My understanding is that the handedness is a mix of what they learn by observing their parents and other people, and of how their brain is wired and/or developed.

While my son was between ½ and 1 year old, he would have one preferred hand for weeks, and then switch to the other hand for weeks. We were guessing whether he'd eventually "land on" right- or left-handedness, but **I saw nothing that could be taken as an early indicator of his final choice.** He's been generally right-handed for a long time now (now 2 years old) so I think it'll stay that way.

---

*The following seems to be [scientifically disproven](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/a/81/3467). I'll leave it in here for the sake of completeness:*

*Most people have a dominant brain half. There's a statistical correlation (meaning it's often but not always the case) regarding the dominant brain haft, with a dominant* left *brain half being correlated to analytical skills and also to right-handedness -- versus creative/artistic skills and left-handedness with a dominant* right *brain half. I'd like to quote some scientific studies here, but perhaps I can fill that in later -- I can't say whether this dominance and handedness is learned, determined by genes, or determined by other factors.*

Comment: @Doug: intriguing! Thank you, I'll edit my answer to reflect this!